# Access em-dosbox memory from console

Tags: emscripten, dosbox

[there's](https://github.com/dreamlayers/em-dosbox) this emscripten port of DosBox (a Dos emulator) which allows running old dos software in-browser. Now what I would like to achieve is to create some sort of memory scanner that allows to tweak some memory values inside the dosbox. I've looked through Google Chrome Profile tab and it shows that DosBox creates one large UInt array that looks like a whole program memory but I have no idea how to access it.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setup of Emscripten puts a `Module` object in the global scope on the page, which contains various views of the array buffer that acts as the memory for the program. For example,

```
Module.HEAPU8
```

is a `Uint8Array` view. Looking in the console at https://archive.org/details/msdos_Prince_of_Persia_1990, which uses Emscripten, the complete list is:

```
Module.HEAP16
Module.HEAP32
Module.HEAPF32
Module.HEAPF64
Module.HEAPU8
Module.HEAPU16
Module.HEAPU32
```

Comment: I was looking to https://archive.org/details/msdos_One_Must_Fall_2097_1994 it has these variables published on window object

Comment: @Lu4 I have a feeling that recent versions of Emscripten don't put all those variables on the global scope, just the Module object (/ function if you use the MODULARIZE option).

Comment: Ok, got it, I've just left a comment for your information (anybodie's)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference, here is the scanner code that I've used

```
class MemoryScanner {
  constructor(target) {
    this.set = new Set();
    this.target = target;
  }

  search(value) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (target[i] === value) {
        set.add(i);
      }
    }
  }

  search2(value1, value2) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (target[i] === value1 && target[i + 1] === value2) {
        set.add(i);
      }
    }
  }

  search4(value1, value2, value3, value4) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (target[i + 0] === value1 &&
          target[i + 1] === value2 &&
          target[i + 2] === value3 &&
          target[i + 3] === value4) {
        set.add(i);
      }
    }
  }

  search8(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (target[i + 0] === value1 &&
          target[i + 1] === value2 &&
          target[i + 2] === value3 &&
          target[i + 3] === value4 &&
          target[i + 4] === value5 &&
          target[i + 5] === value6 &&
          target[i + 6] === value7 &&
          target[i + 7] === value8) {
        set.add(i);
      }
    }
  }

  intersect(value) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;

    for (let index of this.set) {
      if (target[index] !== value) {
        set.delete(index)
      }
    }
  }

  intersect2(value1, value2) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;

    for (let index of this.set) {
      if (target[index] !== value1 || target[index + 1] !== value2) {
        set.delete(index)
      }
    }
  }

  intersect4(value1, value2, value3, value4) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;

    for (let index of this.set) {
      if (target[index + 0] !== value1 ||
          target[index + 1] !== value2 ||
          target[index + 2] !== value3 ||
          target[index + 3] !== value4) {
        set.delete(index)
      }
    }
  }

  intersect8(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8) {
    let target = this.target, length = target.length, set = this.set;

    for (let index of this.set) {
      if (target[index + 0] !== value1 ||
          target[index + 1] !== value2 ||
          target[index + 2] !== value3 ||
          target[index + 3] !== value4 ||
          target[index + 4] !== value5 ||
          target[index + 5] !== value6 ||
          target[index + 6] !== value7 ||
          target[index + 7] !== value8) {
        set.delete(index)
      }
    }
  }
}
```